# Tank Auth - Message: Undefined index: recaptcha_challenge_field

Tags: php, codeigniter, recaptcha, tankauth

Registration with re-Captcha refuses to work on my domain.

I have created a global key for my domain.com and I'm trying to register from dev.domain.com

Whenever I try to register I get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: recaptcha_challenge_field
Filename: controllers/auth.php
Line Number: 580
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please show us lines 560 - 580 from `controllers/auth.php`

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I have found the problem and posted it bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I used my own style in the form, I had

```
<?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string()); ?>
```

accidentaly one div lower that it should have been.

Maybe it will help someone in the future.